# How to filter a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

I have time series data about different stocks. Now I need to filter them according to a threshold (for example threshold = 7). If I now apply the filter function on the data then it filters all values above 7. But what I would need is that the function filters just once per stock. Which means that once a stock exceeded this limit, it should be included in the set, even if it falls below this limit again sometime afterwards. My data is in long format if that helps or is relevant.

If that is the input

```
>              t        value  Stock 
#> 1          1         3         x
#> 2          2         4         x
#> 3          3         5         x
#> 4          4         6         x
#> 5          5         6         x  
#> 6          1         5         y  
#> 6          2         6         y
#> 6          3         7         y
#> 6          4         8         y
#> 6          5         9         y
#> 6          1         6         z
#> 6          2         7         z
#> 6          3         8         z
#> 6          4         5         z
#> 6          5         4         z
```

This should be the output

```
#> 1            t        value  Stock 
#> 2          3         7         y
#> 3          4         8         y
#> 4          5         9         y
#> 5          2         7         z
#> 6          3         8         z
#> 7          4         5         z
#> 8          5         4         z
```

Comment: can you provide example data/code?

Comment: I hope that have explained it a bit better now.

Comment: @Rbeginner not really. You have provided the output but we also need the code necessary to reproduce your data in this example. If you don't provide this, that means that each person has to manually recreate your example, which is quite discouraging. Also, you should see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on how to make a reproducible example

Comment: use dput(df) which gives us something to work with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from your previous example. There is probably a much simpler way to do this, but this should work. There is an additional check for `is.na` on the minimum index crossing the threshold, to detect cases where no values exceed it.

```
threshold <- 7

library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("stock_"), names_to = "stock", names_pattern = "stock_(\\d)$") %>%
  group_by(stock) %>%
  mutate(t = which(value >= threshold)[1]) %>%
  filter(!is.na(t) & row_number() >= t) %>%
  arrange(stock, time) %>%
  select(-t)
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 17 x 3
# Groups:   stock [2]
    time stock value
   <int> <chr> <dbl>
 1     2 2         7
 2     3 2         8
 3     4 2         9
 4     5 2         9
 5     6 2         7
 6     7 2         8
 7     8 2         9
 8     9 2        10
 9    10 2        11
10    11 2        12
11     5 3         7
12     6 3         8
13     7 3         9
14     8 3         5
15     9 3         4
16    10 3         3
17    11 3         6
```

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(
  time = 1:11,
  stock_1 = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 4, 5),
  stock_2 = c(6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12),
  stock_3 = c(3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5, 4, 3, 6)
)
```